# forfiles.exe not working for c:\users\internet\downloads or documents

Tags: windows-7, batch

I am getting could not find c:\users\internet\downloads\new.txt when i run the script in cmd

is it because there's a lock icon on the user account on windows7, the script works fine if i change the location to the c:\test folder

forfiles.exe /P "C:\users\Internet" /S /M *.* /D -7 /C "cmd.exe /c del /Q ""@path""

what i need to do is delete files every 7 days left in my documents and downloads folder, on a generic library account used by everyone at work, it's a windows 7 guest account.

Comment: Have you tried to run cmd as Administrator?

Comment: forget forfiles then for a moment and try the del command on its own on the path. And I suppose you can echo too to check your use forfiles like cld /c echo del /q ""@path"" .... And try the individual commands outside of forfiles. You haven't done basic troubleshooting here and it's possible it's nothing to do with forfiles.

Comment: Did you really use `C:\users\Internet`?? You should use the **real** path to specified directories. Or do you have a `C:\Users\Internet` on your computer?

Comment: The users are logged into local guest account, thats correct so c:\users\internet\downloads and c:\users\internet\documents , by all means I am happy to forget forfiles, and try a regular batch file, looking to delete files 7 days old.

Comment: It's just, i've never seen `C:\Users\Internet` for a guest account. (always `C:\Users\Guest\Downloads`). Are you running this **in** the guest account or in your own account. Also, i had to use `/M *.*` instead of `/M .` to find files.

Comment: sorry i created a local account and called it Internet and then added the guest group to it.

Comment: Remains the question if you're running this as yourself or as "Internet"-user? BTW i see several things wrong with this script but i'll explain in an answer after your answer about which user runs this.

Comment: ok its a library computer so anyone can use them in our organisation, its got auto login its purely used for web surfing, printing and office 2010, its a public computer on a standalone adsl network

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So it's not the `Guest`-account but a `Local account`.

First some small things i noticed about your script.

- If you're going to delete **everything** older than 7 days in **the whole** profile (like your script is doing) you'll get in trouble. You will also delete lots of files in `appdata`, "program settings", etc... You don't want that because those programs could become unusable. The default is, you don't see those files/directories but if you use the command prompt they are there. (Try setting explorer to display hidden files or typing `C:\Users\Internet\appdata` in the address-bar)
- I'm still getting nothing with `/M .`. I need to use `/M *.*` or omit it completly. (default is `/M *`)
- If you are running this as yourself (and not "internet") you don't have enough permission to delete them. (Hence the lock-icon in the file) You need to take ownership of the files before you can delete them. You could try running the script as administrator but i'm not sure if that helps.

There are several ways to tackle this problem. Below i mention another approach about resetting the whole account. But here is a script which deletes files older than 7 days.

It changes the current directory to `C:\Users\Internet` (the `popd` changes it back). Then it loops through a given set of directories from which you want to delete files. You see i didn't specify the **whole** `appdata`-dir but did include the `AppData\Local\Temp` and `Temporary Internet Files`. Add your own if you so desire. It will take ownership (for you) on all files and directories specified. Then it will give `Everyone` rights to those files (so it won't interrupt with their programs). After that only files older than 7 days will be deleted. You need to specify `del /a` to include deleting hidden files.

(I added some checks at the top of the batch-file to make sure your in the right directory. You **really** don't want to do this in another directory by accident.;)

```
@echo off
PUSHD C:\Users\Internet
IF /I "%cd%"=="C:\Users\Internet" GOTO OK
ECHO Oops, CD didn't work. You really don't want to do this in another directory !!!
POPD
EXIT/b
:OK
SET "dirs=AppData\Local\Temp:Contacts:Desktop;Documents:Downloads:Favorites:Links:Music:Pictures:Videos:AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files"
FOR %%d IN ("%dirs::=" "%") DO (
  TAKEOWN /R /D Y /F %%d
  ICACLS %%d /T /GRANT Everyone:F
  FORFILES /P %%d /S /D -7 /C "cmd /c del /q /a "@path""
)
POPD
```

This will not delete "program settings" but will also leave other temp-directories (other than AppData\Local\Temp) alone. So if you have other directories you can include them in the `set`-line.

Another approach would be to reset the whole user-account. You could do

```
net user internet /delete
net user internet /add
rd c:\users\internet /s/q
```

You need to do this as an administrator. But this way **all settings** the user did gets lost. Not only older then 7 days. It will clear everything. Not sure if that's desired. It is however the "cleanest". If it's a public computer you could do this every other day (or every day). You could also backup the profile and restore it but this also deletes younger files and resets the account to a specific time/state.

What is the reason only files older than 7 days should be deleted? If you really want to get to files younger than 7 days you need the first script.